# 'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found - XCode 14.3

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I upgraded my laptop to these specs. My existing React Native app on iOS won't build and I'm not sure why. The one difference I see between my new and old laptop is the framework folder seems to be missing and I don't know how that is created.

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 3.85 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.4.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.4.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.4.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.7.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.4.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.07.10.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34
      Build Tools: 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 33.0.0, 33.0.1, 33.0.2, 34.0.0
      System Images: android-34 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
    Xcode: 14.3.1/14E300c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.7 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-native: 0.67.5 => 0.67.5
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I've tried reinstall the pods and everything seems to install correctly. Any leads or references would be useful. As seen below, Pods_hp_mobile is missing, but on my old laptop the folder actually exists. Thanks.

[image: New Laptop xCode Frameworks]

The pods seem to install correctly as well.

```
npx pod-install
Scanning for pods...
1.11.2
> pod install
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `hp_mobile`: RNAWSCognito, RNBluetoothStateManager, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCPicker, RNDateTimePicker, RNDeviceInfo, RNFBApp, RNFBMessaging, RNGestureHandler, RNNotifee, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, RNSensors, react-native-biometrics, react-native-geolocation-service, react-native-get-random-values, react-native-netinfo, react-native-notifications, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-version-info
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 54 dependencies from the Podfile and 63 total pods installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some native modules are not optimized for the latest Apple CPU architecture (M1, M2).

It's recommended to compile an app by targeting a simulator run through  Rosetta  for backward compatibility: https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3

Comment: Thanks for supplying the link. I had only found the old way of using Rosetta w/ XCode.

Comment: Glad it helps. The old way of enabling Rosetta for Xcode no longer works with latest Xcode version.